# probability and urn

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $6$ black balls numbered from $1$ through $6$ and $8$ white balls numbered from $1$ through $8$, and $3$ green balls numbered from $1$ through $3$. If a ball is drawn at random and it is numbered $3$, what is the probability that the ball is green.

My thoughts:

$$\mathbb{P}(" \text{ green } " | "3")=\mathbb{P}_{"3"}("green")=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(" \text{ green } "\ \cap\ "3")}{\mathbb{P}("3")}=  $$

- $\mathbb{P}("3")=\dfrac{3}{17}$
- $\mathbb{P}( " \text{ green } "\ \cap\ "3" )=\dfrac{1}{17}$

$$\mathbb{P}(" \text{ green } "/ "3")=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

- Is my proof correct i'm interested in many way to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Given that a $3$ has been drawn,
the restricted equiprobable sample space is black $3$, white $3$, and green $3$

Thus P[green $3$] $=\dfrac13$

Comment: so without using  conditional probability

Comment: +1 for your help so without using conditional probability

Comment: You're welcome ! Note that  conditional probability **has** been used, but w/o using the long formula, just by restricting the sample space appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think your solution is correct. Essentially, if you know you have a "3" there could have been three balls that led to it, and there is no reason to assume one of the three is more likely than the others (as every "3"-ball has an equal a priori $\frac{1}{N}$ chance, where $N$ is the total number of balls).

Comment: could you elaborate more please

Comment: @Educ This is the intuition behind the answer, basically. I don't see how it can be much expanded.

Comment: @Educ: Presumably, there is something you don't quite understand or are not sure about.  What is that, as specifically as you can make out?

Comment: @BrianTung i sure about  $\mathbb{P}( " \text{ green } "\ \cap\ "3" )=\dfrac{1}{17}$ and should i pass by this formula $\mathbb{P}(" \text{ green } " | "3")=\mathbb{P}_{"3"}("green")=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(" \text{ green } "\ \cap\ "3")}{\mathbb{P}("3")}$ or we can get resulat direct. thank you

Comment: Using the formula for conditional probability is fine. My reasoning just intuitively confirms the result (or so I hoped).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  +1 thank you